# sum of divisors function $\sum \tau(n) = \frac{1}{4}$

Tags: divergent-series, regularization, multiplicative-function

These notes on [multiplicative number theory](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2014/12/09/254a-notes-2-complex-analytic-multiplicative-number-theory/) mention the convolution $ 1 \ast 1 = \tau$ (where $\tau$ is the [divisor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function) not [Ramanujan tau function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_tau_function).  Therefore

$$ \bigg(\sum \frac{1}{n^s} \bigg)^2 = \sum \frac{\tau(n)}{n^s}$$

At this point, I would like to plug in the value $s =0$ we should get that:

$$ \sum \tau(n) = \bigg(1+1+1+\dots \bigg)^2  
= \bigg( -\frac{1}{2} \bigg)^2 = \frac{1}{4}$$

We could also plug in $s=-1$ to get another relation betweeen divergent sums:

$$ \sum n \tau(n) = \bigg(1+2+3+\dots \bigg)^2  
= \bigg( -\frac{1}{12} \bigg)^2 = \frac{1}{144}$$

One Wikipedia, there is some discussion of the divergent series [$1+1+1+\dots$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_1_%2B_1_%2B_1_%2B_%E2%8B%AF) but the result involves some very complicated analytic continuation.

Are there any simpler ways or summation methods to handle these cases?

---

How do we compute the square of $\zeta(s)$ ?

$$ \zeta(s)^2 =    \bigg(\sum \frac{1}{a^s} \bigg)  \bigg(\sum \frac{1}{b^s} \bigg) =  \sum_{n =1}^\infty \sum_{a \times b=n} \frac{1}{(ab)^s}  = \sum \frac{\tau(d)}{n^s}  $$

How many copies of $\frac{1}{n^s}$ ? One for each factorization $n = a \times b$, this number is called $\tau(d)$.

Example:  $18 = 1 \times 18 = 2 \times 9 = 3 \times 6 = 6 \times 3 = 9 \times 2 = 18 \times 1 $.  So there should be 6 factors, $\frac{6}{18^s}$.

---

There is also must formula for multiplying Dirichlet series.  Sorry I am running out of letters.

$$ \bigg(\sum \frac{a(n)}{n^s} \bigg) \bigg(\sum \frac{b(m)}{m^s} \bigg)
 =  \sum \bigg( \sum_{m \times n = r} a(m)b(n)\bigg)\frac{1}{r^s}  $$

Comment: $\tau (n)$ is a divisor function? Do you mean this : $\sigma_{x}(n)=\sum_{d|n} d^x$? Where $x$ is Real or Complex.

Comment: How did you find the first identity? Might give a clue how to think.

Comment: Ah i now get what you ment at first, i've encounterd the first identity in my philosophy class while someone was talking about why the greek school liked triangles. I'll post the general solution.

Comment: @Gerben Divergent series get hated on in math courses but I trudge on since I see them so often in physics courses.

Comment: If you find analytic continuation hard (and I can almost totally agree) you may be interested in Ramanujan Summation.